# Dark Background of new WPF Ribbon becomes gradient?

Tags: wpf, background, ribbon

I am using the new Version of MS WPF Ribbon (Version MS WPF Ribbon 3.5.40729.1) with Windows 7 and I am trying to change the Background of the Ribbon. Everything looks fine if I use light background colors.

But e.g. if I choose "Black" a white gradient is shown with the black. It does not seem to be possible to remove the white and simply have a black background. And it looks ugly, especially when every Textcolor normally is white. (Tabheaders get white background and are not readable anymore)

In the samples, (I leave everything as is) if I set Background=Black directly in the ribbon's property, the effect is the same.

What do I have to set or do to get rid of the white gradient color?

Comment: This should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154094/styling-ribbon-from-the-ribboncontrolslibrary

Answer (score 2):

There's a hard-coded gloss effect in the `RibbonGroup` template. It's lame, but the only way to get rid of it is to override the temlate for `RibbonGroup`. If you have Blend, just extract the template and rip out the offending `LinearGradientBrush`.

Comment: if we don't have blend? would be nice if you could paste the code? :D